# DocumentDB: Low request charge when reading?

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I have a document which is about 9Kb and with over 250 attributes.

When querying for it (by an unique identifier attribute), the total request charge spent is only around 3 RUs.

According to [MSDN](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/documentdb-manage/), I would expect this to be higher:

> A single request unit represents the processing capacity required to
>   read (via self link) a single 1KB JSON document consisting of 10
>   unique property values. The request unit charge assumes a consistency
>   level set to the default “Session” and all of documents automatically
>   indexed.

The collection is set to use the default indexing (everything is indexed) and is using session consistency.

Could anyone explain why the charge is so low?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DocumentDB's request charge is an abstraction over the CPU, IO and memory required to complete the operation. Unfortunately, there isn't a set formula for calculating request charge.

It's important to point out that the request charge scales logarithmically rather than linearly, in regards to the document size.

Some other things that can affect this include (other than document size):

- Operation Type
- Document Property Count
- Consistency Level
- Number of Indexed Properties
- Indexing Settings

Answer (score 1):

You can use CosmosDB RU calculator which can give you pretty accurate results regarding the RU charges you may incur during read/write operations.

PS - Azure always optimizes and hence you will always get lower RU charges then what you might be expecting ;)

Answer (score 0):

You should also notice, that your document is beeing minified by DocumentDb.